# Mac OS 10.10 Calling defaults read from bash script generates The domain/default pair of does not exist error

Tags: macos, bash

So my goal is to detect the default language of the computer. So I ran this command on the command line:

```
defaults read .GlobalPreferences AppleLanguages | tr -d [:space:] | cut -c2-3
```

And it outputs whatever you set your default language to.

However when I call it from my bash script this it always generates this error:

```
The domain/default pair of (.GlobalPreferences, AppleLanguages) does not exist
```

This is the line that I am calling the defaults command:

```
def_lang=$(defaults read .GlobalPreferences AppleLanguages | tr -d [:space:] | cut -c2-3)
```

Not sure why when calling it directly from the command line it outputs correctly, but from a bash script it errors out.

Comment: Putting those commands in a script and executing it works for me on Yosemite at the Bash prompt.

Comment: However, running the commands with `sudo` reproduces the error message.  I guess the root user does not have these settings.

Comment: Thanks for your input triplee. Other components of the needed to be run as root. Fortunately I found some work around to not need to run as root and now it works.

Comment: Please post that as an answer and mark it as accepted then so that this question no longer comes up as unresolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your input triplee. Your answer is correct. Other components of the needed to be run as root. Fortunately I found some work around to not need to run as root and now it works.

Comment: This was such a long time ago that I forget the exact implementation. I believe I had to make sure that the current user for the script matched the user that I was looking for.